# Method returns variable into its original parameter variable

Tags: python

I am encountering a problem with my program, where a method is saving everything that it does to the parameter variable used in it.

Here's an example: method that moves a list's element to the left by given spaces.

```
def moveLeft (perm, pos, spaces):
   permTemp = perm
   for n in range(spaces):
      charMoved = permTemp[pos-n]
      permTemp [pos-n] = permTemp[pos-n-1]
      permTemp[pos-n-1] = charMoved
   return permTemp

permO = [0,1,2,3] #original perm  
print moveLeft(permO, -1, 2)
print moveLeft(permO, -1, 2)
print permO
```

The expect output would be: the first two to be the same (since it is printing the same returned values of the method) and the last output to be the original list ( [0,1,2,3] ).
Instead I get:

```
    >>> 
[0, 3, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 3, 1]
[0, 2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
permTemp = perm[:]
```

to actually copy the list, instead of just assigning a new name to the same object.

Python assignment does not create new objects, it just names existing ones.  That's why you are modifying the original list.

Comment: That's great, makes a lot more sense now! This must be different that what happens in Java because I have never experienced this problem before!

Comment: No, Java would do the same thing, it also uses references to objects, so saying `int[] arr = {1,2,3};  int[]arr2 = arr;  arr2[1] = -2;` would modify the original array.  There is a `System.arrayCopy()` method which will make actual copies.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sven's list copy, but note also that you don't need a temporal variable to swap values:

```
def moveLeft(perm, pos, spaces):
   permTemp = perm[:]
   for n in range(spaces):
      permTemp[pos-n], permTemp[pos-n-1] = permTemp[pos-n-1], permTemp[pos-n]
   return permTemp
```

Comment: Thank you, that saves a lot of time!